# Библиотека на Python

Tags: python

Существует ли библиотека на Python для распознавания текста и цифр?

Comment: вопрос не ясен. в каком виде представлен текст? внесите, пожалуйста, уточнение прямо в текст вопроса, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 3):

1. [OCR для питона](http://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/11/ocr-python-easy/)
2. [Pytesser](https://github.com/RobinDavid/Pytesser)
3. [Туториал как сервер распознавания картинок поднять](https://realpython.com/blog/python/setting-up-a-simple-ocr-server/)

Можно гулить "python text recognition", "python ocr bindings" и т.д., есть много материалов.